# Add to pattern for preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm using the following pattern which basically strips anything from a string that is not a number preceded by a currency symbol:

```
$pattern = '/\p{Sc}\s*\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?/u';
```

But, as the string i'm matching can be html source code, this is not perfect as sites in the UK do not always use "£" for a value, they may use `&pound;` or `&#163;`

```
A price might be listed as £10.00 or &pound;10.00 or &#163;10.00
```

So what I'm asking is, is it possible to add those into the mix when using `p{Sc} /u`

Comment: Those other ones are also encoded as a single code point, right?

Comment: Updated code, SO had rendered it html so the question was illogical

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a character class with all of those included.

```
[\p{Sc}\p{...}\p{...}]
```

EDIT:

You can use `html_entity_decode` to convert the entities in the string to the relevant characters before you use the regex on it.

```
$string = html_entity_decode("A price might be listed as £10.00 or &pound;10.00 or &#163;10.00");
$pattern = '/\p{Sc}\s*\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?/u';
$matches = [];
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
```